# Tried prepare similar table for my data for t test i

Tags: r, p-value, t-test

Desired outcome:

[image: Required Table]

Code I Tried

```
dataset <- data.frame(
  Tags = c("Tags43", "Tags276", "Tags420", "Tags480"),
  Control_1 = c(8981963.746, 12345.67, 718507.1299, 296607.9652),
  Control_2 = c(8881963.746, 23456.78, 718517.1299, 296617.9652),
  Control_3 = c(8986963.746, 34567.89, 718507.1299, 296607.9652),
  Treatment_1 = c(27024800.41, 98765.43, 922388.9052, 2431785.914),
  Treatment_2 = c(27024800.41, 87654.32, 922388.9052, 2431785.914),
  Treatment_3 = c(27024800.41, 76543.21, 922388.9052, 2431785.914)
)

# Reshape the data into long format
long_data <- dataset %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Tags, names_to = "Group", values_to = "Value") %>%
  separate(Group, into = c("Group", "Replicate"), sep = "_")

# Calculate mean and SD for each Tag-Group combination
summary_data <- long_data %>%
  group_by(Tags, Group) %>%
  summarise(
    Mean = mean(Value),
    SD = sd(Value)
  )

# Arrange the data for final output
final_data <- summary_data %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Group, values_from = c(Mean, SD)) %>%
  mutate(
    Control = paste0(format(round(Control_Mean, 2), nsmall = 2), " ± ", format(round(Control_SD, 2), nsmall = 2)),
    Treatment = paste0(format(round(Treatment_Mean, 2), nsmall = 2), " ± ", format(round(Treatment_SD, 2), nsmall = 2))
  ) %>%
  select(Tags, Control, Treatment)

# Print the final arranged table
print(final_data)
```

Some error is occuring in the code while calculating mean±SD. Also help to calculate Fold change (Formula is log2(Treatment/Control). Attach * or ** along with Fold change.

I observed

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `Control = paste0(...)`.
ℹ In group 1: `Tags = "Tags2"`.
Caused by error:
! object 'Control_Mean' not found
```

Comment: Hi Learner, you will find a lot of friends here, if you provide a bit of context and/or why your code is not producing the desired result. It might also be helpful to take it in steps. Is your first code fragment, i.e. long_data, giving you what you want? The `summary_data` is a valid grouped operation. Thus, if there is an error in the `mean` and `sd` you expect ... was your input data (long_data) well-formed? The error basically tells you that you call a column, i.e. `Control_Mean` that does not exist in your `summary_data`. Thus, you would need to correct your `round()` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ray, I got error fixed. Kindly help to calculate Fold change (Formula is log2(Treatment/Control). Attach * or ** along with Fold change

Comment: Again, it is inherently difficult to understand what your issues are and where you code does not do what you expect it to do when you do not post a reproducible example. The formula you are listing can be readily calculated using something along the lines of ` ... |> mutate(Fold = log2(Treatment/Control))`. Make sure you format the output columns once you have all data columns calculated. This avoids that you have to split strings, etc. Good luck